# Inserting content script in all new tabs opened from a particular tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am building a Record/Playback chrome extension where the user can click a browser action to start the recording of his actions. This will insert a Content Script into the current active tab and start sending the actions to the background script. The challenging part is when the user clicks a link which opens a new window/tab and a script, the `background.js` keeps a track of new tabs created using `chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener` and inserts the content script into the newly created tab if its [Opener Tab ID, `openerTabId`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) is same as the ID of the starting tab.

The whole methods seems a bit clunky to me. Is this the best way?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking here. What seems clunky and in which way?

Answer (score 1):

[Programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) discussed that inserting code into a page programmatically is useful when your JavaScript or CSS code shouldn't be injected into every single page that matches the pattern — for example, if you want a script to run only when the user clicks a browser action's icon.

To insert code into a page, your extension must have cross-origin permissions for the page. It also must be able to use the `chrome.tabs` module. Once you have permissions set up, you can inject JavaScript into a page by calling `tabs.executeScript`. And as stated too, instead of inserting code directly, it's usually done by putting the code in a file like this:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
```

Other than that, this SO post - [Chrome extension: create tab then inject content script into it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009637/chrome-extension-create-tab-then-inject-content-script-into-it) might help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add content_script.js to 
 and check that tab is new tab with

```
if(history.length == 1){
    // TODO: something
}
```